# Write mat files with custom extension

Tags: matlab, save

I have a folder containing `file.nir` and `file.nirs`. I can open those files and process, but I don't know how to save it as `.nir` and `.nirs` file after processing.

Here is the code how I can open the file:

```
 file='path/file.nirs'

 d=load(file, '-mat'); % d is an object
 data=d.d'; % data of the experiment
 save(data, '-nirs') %% EROR: I could not save it here
```

How I can save it as `nirs` file? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `save(file, data, '-mat')`?

Comment: the idea is save it as nirs file not a mat file :)

Comment: it gives me an error: Error using save
Argument must contain a string.

Comment: `save(file, 'data', '-mat')`?

Comment: The extension is `nirs`, but the format is `mat`?

Comment: Can you provide a sample `nir` file?

Comment: @m7913d  Still the same error

Comment: @ m7913d: Yes, it is

Comment: @sardar Usama: How I can send it for you?

Comment: If it contains simple text, upload that in the question. Otherwise upload it on some cloud (google drive etc)

Comment: I think I found how to do that: it's as follow: save('MyTestfile.nirs','d','t','ml','SD','StimDesign','-MAT');

Comment: Thanks every body for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provide you can:

- Save the data as .mat if you are only using it in MATLAB
- Save the file using string manipulation to make it look as the original file, by doing that you can put the .nirs extension and whatever program you use afterwards will be able to open it.

Regardless, could you provide more information?

Comment: Thanks Xaime..The problem is sloved! Thanks